# Is there a way in Java to check if a concrete class implements an external interface with same fully qualified name?

Tags: java, interface

Sorry if the question title is not clear but I needed more characters to fully explain myself.

Before people start jumping to conclusions, YES I know about isInstance and instanceof but hear me out first.

Let's say I generate a java ".class" file of an interface (called MyInterface) from a UML model. Then, lets say that there is a directory somewhere that contains two ".class" files where one represents an interface that is IDENTICAL to the generated one (same fully qualified name, both using the default package) and the other represents the concrete class that implements MyInterface.

In a separate program, I load in the generated interface and concrete class with separate classloaders (URLClassLoader). When I try to check if the concrete class implements the generated version of the interface, isInstance() returns False. I suspect this is because when the concrete class is loaded, the non-generated interface gets pulled in with it because it implements it. If I use Class.getInterfaces() on the concrete class and compare it's interface with the generated one using equals, this also fails.

Since isInstance() does not work does anyone know of a way to  verify that a class implements an interface with the same fully qualified name and not necessarily the one it was compiled with?

Comment: Did you try reflection?

Comment: @RodrigoGomes Yes I am using reflection to actually invoke the methods of the implementing class but if I cannot check to see if that class actually implements the interface for which I am getting the method names, then I would have to manually catch the NoSuchMethodExceptions. Which I'm trying to avoid if I can.

Comment: Ok... Now, did you try Aspect? you can intercept the request of a specific class that implements a specific interface ;)

Comment: Are you referring to Aspect-Oriented Programming? I did a quick search and that is what came up. Do you have a link to somewhere that explains how to do what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be too worried about whether this is good practice or not, you could simply compare against Class.getInterfaces() but with a custom comparison (name based, or more involved if you want to make sure operations are good too).

Just scan the interfaces and look for one that matches, but don't ask the default "equals" to work for you because of the way you're cheating with the classloader.

BTW, I'd definitely put code that catches the NoSuchMethod cleanly, it's bound to happen at some point the whole setup seems fragile.

Comment: Yeah after seeing the other answers this looks like the best option moving forward. Initially I was trying to avoid something like this but I guess I might not have a choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say I generate a java ".class" file of an interface (called MyInterface) from a UML model. Then, lets say that there is a directory somewhere that contains two ".class" files where one represents an interface that is IDENTICAL to the generated one (same fully qualified name, both using the default package) and the other represents the concrete class that implements MyInterface.

Why? This is poor practice. Don't do it.

> In a separate program, I load in the generated interface and concrete class with separate classloaders (URLClassLoader). When I try to check if the concrete class implements the generated version of the interface, isInstance() returns False. I suspect this is because when the concrete class is loaded, the non-generated interface gets pulled in with it because it implements it.

No. It is because you are using two classloaders. Classes loaded by distinct classloaders are distinct.

> If I use Class.getInterfaces() on the concrete class and compare it's interface with the generated one using equals, this also fails.

For the same reason.

> Since isInstance() does not work does anyone know of a way to verify that a class implements an interface with the same fully qualified name and not necessarily the one it was compiled with?

You can't. The only way the class and the interface can coexist in the same same JVM is via distinct classloaders, which eliminates the implements-relation between them.

The solution is simply not to do this in the first place.

Comment: First, just because something is considered poor practice doesn't mean that there isn't a valid reason to do it. 

Second, yes I understand that because I am using two classloaders that it breaks the implements-relation between them but obviously having two interfaces with the same name loaded with the same classloader will not allow me to differentiate between them.

I guess maybe I should be asking the question of if other people have found a way to programatically verify that the implementation matches the UML model.

Comment: It's poor practice*because* there isn't a solution. What cogent reason can you advance for having a class that implements an interface of exactly the same name? What's going to break if you change the name? And BTW how can you possibly compile such a class in the first place?

Comment: Okay. I really don't think you understand why I am doing this so let me try to explain more clearly. I'm not sure what your background is but in my world, and for most large programs, the Systems Engineers have to test all public interfaces between program elements to make sure they adhere to the design model they created. When it comes to development, the SW Engineers will base their design and implementation off of the model. When they do that they go and create their own classes and interfaces in their development environment (which is not necessarily the same environment that the model ...

Comment: ...is produced in). When development is done, the Systems Engineers have to verify that the implementation matches the design and requirements that are in the model. I am trying to create a program that will compare the interfaces generated in the model to the interfaces created by the SW Engineers and then use reflection to actually invoke and test the implementation of those interfaces. In order to do that I need to check that the concrete classes are implementing the interfaces that are in the model. If they are different, then either the implementation or the model needs to change. It's...

Comment: ...simply an automated testing program. Does that not seem like a valid reason to you? If it is not possible then its not possible but that doesn't mean I can't at least ask first before looking into other ways of doing what I'm doing. At least the answer by @Yann TM actually recognizes that I have my reasons for doing this and then attempts to give me a helpful solution. I appreciate your help since it is nice to know that what I'm trying to do is probably not possible, but I feel like you are assuming that I have no idea what I'm doing and then just shutting down...

Comment: ...everything I am asking; which is less helpful.

Comment: And to actually answer your question, the compiled code is still going to be isolated from the generated, identical, interfaces. I am just pulling them into a separate, completely isolated, program for the sole purpose of testing. The system itself will not have naming conflicts because the generated interfaces will not exist in that environment